# Connecting to Azure with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure

How do you connect to Azure with Powershell? I'm specifically referring to the Service Manager system, not with Resource Manager.  Also, does it make more sense to use certificates or connect with a username/password?

Answer (score 3):

I have had hundreds of people ask me the same question...

To Connect to the service manager in Azure (AKA Standard Portal) with PowerShell, there are two ways.

1. `Add-AzureAccount`
2. `Get-AzurePublishSettingsFile`

I generally prefer certificate (PublishSettingsFile) but either is fine.

The following is what that code might look like...

`Add-AzureAccount`

OR

```
Get-AzurePublishSettingsFile #Download the Certificate from Azure 
Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile –PublishSettingsFile "C:_Data\Downloads\BizSpark-8-17-2015-credentials.publishsettings"

# Set Default Subscription
Get-AzureSubscription

Set-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName "Internal Consumption"

# Test Connection:
Get-AzureVM
```

Disclaimer: I work for Microsoft and my primary (and official) blog is located at http://itproguru.com